# Using a return variable from a function elsewehere in c

Tags: arrays, c, string, cs50

I am quite new to coding and stuck on the following problem:

Basically, I need to attach two strings or arrays to each other. This string/array I need to use in the main function for code I still have to write. However, the code works if I execute it right now and with `printf("%s", c);` it correctly prints 52 characters. The problem is that I cannot find a way to use string/array c in my main function (I need to go through each letter of my input text and change it with the letter + 26).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

char merge(string a, string b, string c);

int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
        string text = get_string("Type your text: \n");
        char abc[26] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        char full[52];

        merge(abc, argv[1], full);
        
}

char merge(string a, string b, string c)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a) + strlen(b); i++)
    {
        if (i < strlen(a))
        {
          c[i] = a[i];
        }
        else
        {
          c[i] = b[i - strlen(a)];
        }
    }
   return c[2];
}
```

Comment: `char abc[26]` should be `char abc[27]`. You didn't add an element for the null terminator.

Comment: Or just use `char abc[]` and it will make it the correct length automatically.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The `full` array in the main function corresponds to `c` in the `merge` function.

Comment: You need to add a null terminator at the end of the loop.

Comment: Are you prohibited from using `strcpy()` and `strcat()`? They would simplify `merge()`.

Comment: @Barmar The thought of the ```full``` array was to create an array of length 52 to use as input for the function (string c). My question is how can I use the output (being an array of string a and b) in the rest of my code?

Comment: The loop can be replaced with: `strcpy(c, a); strcat(c, b);`

Comment: it's input AND output. The function is modifying its contents.

Comment: No I am not prohibited to use those (first time I hear about them), but I am not familiar them

Comment: When an array is used as a function argument, it's converted to a pointer to its first element. So assigning to elements of `c` will modify `full`.

Comment: Ah yes of course, I should have noticed that before. Thanks man